# How to setting firebase remote config for unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

lets to the point, so i want to make some configuration with my game to show Ads but I avoid to update game version too much, because of that I choose firebase remote config with this I can update setting/configuration without update the game version.

there is document for this but not very clear for newbie like me, you can check it here https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-unity

I already make the script like on doc, but I don't understand how its work on show data because error string format, which is what I know on this firebase console is int format
[image]

the script like this :

```cs
public static _FirebaseRemoteConfig instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                InitializeFirebase();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> defaults =
            new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        defaults.Add("config_test_string", "default local string");
        defaults.Add("config_test_int", 1);
        defaults.Add("config_test_float", 1.0);
        defaults.Add("config_test_bool", false);

        Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.SetDefaults(defaults);
        Debug.Log("Remote config ready!");
    }
    public void FetchFireBase()
    {
        FetchDataAsync();
    }
    public void ShowData()
    {
        Debug.Log("maxCountToShowAdmob: " +
            Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("MaxCountShowIntersitialAds").LongValue);
    }

    // Start a fetch request.
    public Task FetchDataAsync()
    {
        Debug.Log("Fetching data...");
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task fetchTask = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.FetchAsync(
            TimeSpan.Zero);
        return fetchTask.ContinueWith(FetchComplete);
    }

    void FetchComplete(Task fetchTask)
    {
        if (fetchTask.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch canceled.");
        }
        else if (fetchTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch encountered an error.");
        }
        else if (fetchTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Fetch completed successfully!");
        }

        var info = Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.Info;
        switch (info.LastFetchStatus)
        {
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Success:
                Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched();
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).",
                    info.FetchTime));
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Failure:
                switch (info.LastFetchFailureReason)
                {
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Error:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch failed for unknown reason");
                        break;
                    case Firebase.RemoteConfig.FetchFailureReason.Throttled:
                        Debug.Log("Fetch throttled until " + info.ThrottledEndTime);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Pending:
                Debug.Log("Latest Fetch call still pending.");
                break;
        }
    }
```